# Guitar FX Program?

Tags: music

I am in a sort band, with my friends.  We have nothing official, and no money.  I am looking into a small computer to put Ubuntu on for music during practice sessions and guitar effects, as none of us have the money to put up for a pedal.

I am looking for a simple effects program that can use MIDI inputs, as well as keys on my keyboard to trigger different pedals.  I am really set on using keys because I have a "Makey Makey," which I can use to trigger certain ones.

Ideally, this would be something free and easy, though I am also always interested in wrapping my mind around a new concept.

Answer (score 0):

"Guitar Rig" is pretty popular. I heard it could be a little tricky to set up properly though.

Or [this](http://rakarrack.sourceforge.net/dl.html).

Comment: I tried Rackarrack, all it did was mess up my sound.  I will have to try Guitar Rig.  Thanks.

Comment: All I can find it Guitar Rig for Windows and I would rather not go through Wine, as some of my hardware doesn't like emulation like that.